# Are SSL certificates linked to current hosting I use?

Tags: ssl, hosting

I am new to SSL certificates and trying to install one from https://letsencrypt.org with [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org).

I see that I need to prove I own the domain by putting a file accessible from the web that to hosting running that domain.

When I get the certificate, will it be somehow locked to the hosting I use or can I just put the files somewhere on my computer then upload them once I deploy on this or that hosting environment?

Comment: No, they're not locked to the hosting provider.

Comment: The certificate is only locked to the private key.  Any server with that private key can use that certificate, so you want to be sure to protect that private key file.

Comment: The question is though, even if you procure the certificates, will your hosting allow you to place them? You need to be able to reload your webserver, bind to port 443 and stuff like that. If it's on a shared hosting, you probably won't be able to do anything of the sort. On the other hand, the certificates you get from lets encrypt, you can use them wherever you can load them into the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> , will it be somehow locked to the hosting I use or can I just put the files somewhere on my computer then upload them once I deploy on this or that hosting environment?

No, absolutely not. Once you get the certificate you can move private key and fullchain/server certificate anywhere. Move it to another server which is going to host that domain/SAN(subject alternate name)